# Convert String of "0" and "1" to image by php

Tags: php

PHP to convert a standard input of 1’s and 0’s to set an specific pixel color of my choice.

Where each bit present a pixel, and `\n` a new row.

**Example:**
For This Given String
`1010\n0101\n1010\n0101\n1010\`  image looks chess board.

Comment: Did you have a look at [the GD module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)?

Comment: @leemes thank you let me check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my sample code, hope this can help you^^

```
<?php
$size = 50; /*the square size*/
$map = "0101\n1010\n0101\n1010"; /*your image map*/


$totalRow = 0;
$totalCol = 0;

$rows = explode("\n", $map); /* split map by '\n' as the requirement stated*/
$totalRow = count($rows); /* get total row */

/**
 * Convert map to array make it loopable
 */
$map = [];
foreach ($rows as $row)
{

    $cols = str_split($row); /* use str_split to split each characters */
    $totalCol = $totalCol < count($cols) ? count($cols) : $totalCol; /* get biggest cols user to calculate image width*/

    $map[] = $cols; /* push to map*/

}

/**
 * Create image
 */
$width = $size * $totalCol; /* width = size * biggest cols*/
$height = $size * $totalRow; /* height = size * total rows*/
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); /* create image */

/**
 * Colors
 */
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

/**
 * Build square
 */
$x = 0; /* x pointer*/
$y = 0; /* y pointer*/

foreach ($map as $mapRow) /* rows loop*/
{
    foreach ($mapRow as $square) /* cols loop */
    {
        $color = $square == 1 ? $black : $white; /* black if the code is '1'*/

        // create square
        imagefilledrectangle($im, $x, $y, $x + $size, $y + $size, $color);

        $x += $size; /* increase x pointer*/
    }

    $x = 0;  /* reset x pointer */
    $y += $size; /* increase y pointer*/
}

/* png header */
header('Content-Type: image/png');

/* show image */
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: how to check the string is binary or not because string is dynamic

Comment: @GautamJha that mean the string can only contains '\n', '0' and '1' ?

Comment: OK i can fix then

Comment: @GautamJha sorry for waiting, maybe you can add `if(!preg_match("/^[01\n\r]*$/", $map)) die('error');` below `$map = "0101\n1010\n0101\n1010";` ^^

Comment: if i am give value form `input text` it gives me error

Comment: The error is cuase by the input '\n' is not acture new line, you can use simple solve by after `$map = $_POST['map'];` 
    you add a php replace like this `$map = str_replace('\n', "\n", $map);`, then only run the validation code
    `if(!preg_match("/^[01\n\r]*$/", $map)) die('error format');`. Hope this help ^^